# Directory hierarchy working with IntelliJ and Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, struts2, intellij-idea

I recently started working with Struts 2 with Intellij IDEA Ultimate 13.1 and I seem to be running into a lot of trouble with getting my JSP pages to link to my struts2 java files and i think it has to do with directories.

I created the Struts2 project from `New Project` -> `Java project` - > `Web` -> `Struts 2`.

The `project/web/WEB-INF` folder only held my `web.xml` and as far as I can tell that's where a `src` folder and a few other important folders should be. So I've been putting my Struts2 `src` files inside of my project src folder because IntelliJ recognizes what they should be, additionally that's where my `struts.xml` is placed.

So my question is, does IntelliJ require my Struts2 java files to be stored in the directories above? If so, how do i reference things in my JSP when `<s:form>`, etc. can't be grabbed by `/struts-tags`?

Any help working with the current IntelliJ update and with Struts2 would be of huge help in general.

Comment: I've mostly solved my own problem. I went into Project Settings and added a Source folder to WEB-INF as well as a few other important hierarchical changes. As I think Roman C was trying to get across, the directory can be more fluid than I was giving it credit for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime you feel like making extra folders yourself will not hurt you and project structure that used with different types of projects might very. But you can always restructure it the way you want.

You need to set the source folder and compiled out for the project. If you are doing a web project you might also specify the web content root. All of these things to map such folders in the project structure are transparent. The wizard just creates a predefined structure.

You should know that a Maven project which you could run with the IntelliJ IDEA has it's own project structure and it's possible due to the talked above.

So, you are free to create your own folders and content of your project and modules, and edit them in the corresponding editor. IntelliJ IDEA has a plugin for Struts 2 but I don't remember if I ever used its features, since I moved to the annotation based configuration.

Also I pay zero attention to JSP's errors that occurred in the JSP file editor. How they are mapped to the actions - see in the configuration, or even better by browsing a runtime configuration via config-browser plugin. It could be XML based configuration, or annotation based configuration, or both.

More over you can write your own configuration provider that  IntelliJ IDEA plugin unable to handle. If you are learning the framework and like to automate some code using wizards or templates the IDE can help you, but if you are doing complex things it always fails. Never mind, just do what you want and know how it works.